# Empty array returned by var_dump($_POST); though not var_dump($_GET);

Tags: php, post, get

I am running PHP 7.0.22 on two ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS servers: a web server and an app server.  They are both instances of AWS EC2.

When I have the following code on the app server

```
<form action="http://example.com/uploadFiles.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file" style="font-size:5mm; font-family:times-new-roman">Select up to 20 filenames:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple="multiple"/></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit[]" value="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" id="LoggedIn" name="LoggedIn" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="setName" name="setName" value="<?php echo $setName ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="UserName" name="UserName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['UserName'] ?>">
</form>
```

and the following code in uploadFiles.php on the web server

```
<html>
<body>

<?php  require("menu.php"); ?>
<?php
 var_dump($_GET);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I get

```
array(5) { ["file"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "file.name" } ["submit"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "submit" } ["LoggedIn"]=> string(1) "1" ["setName"]=> string(4) "test" ["UserName"]=> string(12) "OtagoHarbour" }
```

However, if I have the following code on the app server

```
<form action="http://example.com/uploadFiles.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file" style="font-size:5mm; font-family:times-new-roman">Select up to 20 filenames:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple="multiple"/></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit[]" value="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" id="LoggedIn" name="LoggedIn" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="setName" name="setName" value="<?php echo $setName ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="UserName" name="UserName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['UserName'] ?>">
</form>
```

and the following code in uploadFiles.php on the web server

```
<html>
<body>

<?php  require("menu.php"); ?>
<?php
 var_dump($_POST);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I get

```
array(0) { }
```

Is there a way to get what I am getting with GET using POST?

I do not know of this is relevant but I did not have this problem before I set SSL up  on my website.

Comment: have you checked it in `$_FILES`?

Comment: var_dump($_FILES)  also returns array(0) { } .  Thanks,

Comment: @OtagoHarbour What happens if you change `http://` to `https://`?

Comment: That fixed it.  That's interesting.  Thanks,

Comment: There was a redirect i think from http to https

Comment: @Simon Müller  Yes there was a redirect from http to https.  I had not realized that it would affect POST.  Thanks,